# How to remove Column in crystal report if Column value have NULL

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am dynamically adding columns to a crystal reports data source as explained here [Dynamic_Reports](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-dynamic-crystal-reports.htm).

Here i need remove columns whenever i am not filling values to depends upon columns. These columns are i need to remove from a crystal reports at run time.
Why i need like this means,I have 20 columns and going fill 1st ,2nd ,19th and 20th columns Only.Rest of them having blank space.blank space[columns] are need to remove.

Answer (score 0):

Include a formula checking null value for the particular column and if null dont insert. These you can check after filling in the database.

EDIT:

example:

```
If  !IsNull({Product.Color}) Or InStr({Product.Color}, " ") != 0  Then
   totext({Table.Column})
```

You can drag the required column for which you suspect it will be blank in to the `( )` of `IsNull` or `InStr`

Comment: at run time i can not get "{Table.Column}" fields when it come empty from Data Table. it showing error like "This field name is not known" in this formula.